# Django 1.11 ignoring on_delete=models.set_null

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project with a model, something like this:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)


class Disc(models.Model):
    a_side_disc = models.ForeignKey(Track, null=True,
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    b_side_disc = models.ForeignKey(Track, null=True,
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    in_jukebox = models.BooleanField()
```

This model is totally made up, and don't make sense, but it shows my current setup in this case.

Now with Django 1.11 and Django Restframework, I have a route with a delete for a Track. When I call the Route, I check if the Track is on a Disc with in_jukebox set to False. If that is the case I simply go on with the delete. 
I expect that both ForeignKeys in Disc are set to Null, but instead Disc is deleted as well like I would expect from CASCADE.

I use Postgres as database, and inspected the generated Schema. I understand that SET_NULL is done by django and not the database. But it is not done.
 Am I understanding somthing wrong? Which direction is on_delete working, and if it's only one, how do I make the same on the other side?

Comment: I just stumbled over this after installing Postgres 10. What version of Postgresql are you using?

Comment: @Daniel I use postgres 10.1

Comment: I figured out that I had an orphaned contraint in my database from an earlier migration, where I introduced `SET_NULL`. The new contrainst was added, but the old not updated. I manually deleted the orphaned constrained and all was good. BTW, SET NULL is part of the constraint in PostgreSQL.

Comment: In my attemped to fix this, I recreated the database, so there should not be an orphaned constraint there. I as well looked through migrations and reset the questioned migrations as well. I can not provide a source, but I've read several times that SET_NULL etc. can be done as constraint in PostgreSQL, but is said to be done by Django (not sure about this anymore and if you say I am wrong, I probably am :D)
I made a workaround and moved on with other bugs to fix, if there is time in the next days I will have a look at this again.

Comment: Actually, the `on_delete` constraints are handled by Django and not in SQL. There is an open ticket which discusses this issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961